# Bash script to write Log Processing output to remote DB2

Tags: shell, db2

I have a bash script running on a server to capture and process the Logs. 
The script is invoked by an utility for processing the Logs. After processing the Logs the 
state of the Logs should be stored in db2 table located in some other server. 
say, if i have shell script on 110.88.99.10 and db2 on 110.88.99.11..
I need save the processed result to db2.. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you need to install the DB2 client: IBM data server access. Once you have installed, you configure the remote instance and database (catalog TCPIP Node and catalog database), and then you can integrate db2 commands (db2 insert ... - log result) in your script.